# Why does setting the TextBoxWidth property of the SearchBoxEx causes the page to crash and only works back if I undo check out

Tags: search

I am new to SharePoint and I am customizing the search control, I replaced the search DelegateControl with the following as some article suggests,

```
<SPSWC:SearchBoxEx webpart="true" runat="server" CssClass="searchInput" SearchResultPageUrl="/Pages/SearchResults.aspx" __WebPartId="{344821C7-B621-4B99-AC49-A82C9B00356E}">
            <WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
            <Title></Title>
            <Description></Description>
            <FrameType>None</FrameType>
            <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
            <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
            <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
            <GoImageUrl xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:SearchBoxEx">
            /Resources/Common/Images/searchButton.png</GoImageUrl>
            <GoImageActiveUrl xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:SearchBoxEx">
            /Resources/Common/Images/searchButton.png</GoImageActiveUrl>
            <GoImageUrlRTL xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:SearchBoxEx">
            /Resources/Common/Images/searchButton.png</GoImageUrlRTL>
            <GoImageActiveUrlRTL xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:SearchBoxEx">
            /Resources/Common/Images/searchButton.png</GoImageActiveUrlRTL>
            <DropDownModeEx xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:SearchBoxEx">
            HideScopeDD_DefaultContextual</DropDownModeEx>
            <ID>g_344821c7_b621_4b99_ac49_a82c9b00356e</ID>
            </WebPart>
        </SPSWC:SearchBoxEx>
```

I also added the the following Register directive to the top of the page,

```
<%@ Register tagprefix="SPSWC" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Now when I set the TextBoxWidth property on the SearchBoxEx the whole page crashes and never works again even if I remove the property until I undo check out the changes made to the page, so any idea about this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: exceptions and logs please (<sharepointroot>\logs)

Comment: Well I figured it out, the exception says "Some value" can't be value of "DropDownModeEx", and in the end it sounded to be sharepoint designer problem or system problem I just restarted the system and reapplied the same thing and it worked like magic.

Comment: Ok please add that as answer to this question then. After a couple of days you can set as answer and get the rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments all that was required was to reboot the system

> Well I figured it out, the exception says "Some value" can't be value
>   of "DropDownModeEx", and in the end it sounded to be sharepoint
>   designer problem or system problem I just restarted the system and
>   reapplied the same thing and it worked like magic